# galois group of $x^6 - 5 x^4 + 4 x^2 + 1$

Tags: polynomials, field-theory, galois-theory

> Find the Galois field of $x^6 - 5 x^4 + 4 x^2 + 1$ over $\mathbb Q$

well, I found that $x^6 - 5 x^4 + 4 x^2 + 1=x^2(x-2)(x-1)(x+1)(x+2)+1$
this means that if $\alpha$ is a root than $-\alpha$ is a root too.
it means $C_2$ is a subgroup of it.
I haven't managed to find the entire structure of the galois group.

Comment: In other words you realized your polynomial is a cubic applied to $x^2$.

Comment: That's a way simpler way.